# How to hide top nav bar and bottom while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to hide top nav bar and bottom while scrolling feeds? i want to hide top nav bar and bottom nav bar while scrolling the feed what can be a better approach to do that? like if a user scroll feeds it hides and when a user stop scroll it come back again for scrolling feeds i am using flashlist

```
 return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar />
            <BottomNavigation navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />
            <TopNavigation navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />
            <Feeds navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [onScrollBeginDrag](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscrollbegindrag) and [onMomentumScrollEnd](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview.html#onmomentumscrollend) to detect when view (ScrollView, FlatList, etc) is scrolling and use derived state for conditional rendering.

```
const [isScrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false) 

...
<View>
  {!isScrolling && <YourComponent/>}
  <ScrollView
    onScrollBeginDrag={() => setScrolling(true)}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={() => setScrolling(false)}
...
  />
</View>
```

Comment: is using scroll view impact my app performance ?

Comment: also which youromponent you talking about?